# If U=Max X,Y,Z, find F(u) and f(u)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Given independent, identically distributed random variables X, Y, and Z each with the probability density $f(x)=6x^5  for \ 0\leq x \leq 1$

a. Find the joint probability distribution
This part is simple enough. Since all the random variables are independent, we just get $f(x,y,z)=6^3x^5y^5z^5$, right?

b. Let U=Maximum of X,Y,Z. Find the distribution function F(u) and the density function f(u)

I'm a little lost on part b. Here is what I have so far:

$F_u(u)=P(U\leq u)$

$=P(Max\{ X, Y, Z\} \leq u)$

$=P(X\leq u)P(Y\leq u)P(Z\leq u)$

$=F_x(u)F_y(u)F_z(u)$

$F_x=F_y=F_z$, so it should be as simple as figuring out one. I guess I am lost as to what to do with u.

Finding f(u) is just a simple derivative, so I don't really need help with that. When it comes to F(u) and what I've worked out above, would I want to take the original probability density given and compute the integral (which would be F(x)) raise it to the third power and plug in u for the variable? That seems too easy to be right, so I would appreciate some feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is that easy.   That is exactly what you need to do.

Now, the CDF is the integral of the pdf up to that point. $$F_Z(u)=F_Y(u)=F_X(u) ~=~ \int_0^u f_X(s)\operatorname d s\cdot \mathbf 1_{0\leq u < 1}+ \mathbf 1_{u\geq 1}$$

So just find that, and then $F_U(u)= F_X(u)^3$ and $f_U(u) = 3f_X(u)F_X(u)^2$ as you figured.

---

PS: It is a good idea to subscript those functions to distinguish between them.

Comment: So my final answer becomes F_u(u)=u^18? Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: @LidStar To be complete, $F_U(u) = \begin{cases} 0 &:& u\leq 0 \\ u^{18}&:& 0<u<1\\ 1 &:& u\geq 1\end{cases}$